# jQuery not working on loaded content

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I am working on a site where the content loads itself (through an Ajax call) into a div box that appears in the center of the screen when the user clicks an option on the menu. The issue I am having is that I can't figure out why none of the javascript/jquery code seems to work on any of the loaded content. I need to re-declare all of the javascript and jquery files in the loaded content itself for it to run.

Essentially, the user clicks "User List" from the menu:

```
    $('#users_list').live("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.prompt_content').load('users.php?page=1', function() {
        showprompt();
    });
    });
```

Then the div box appears at the center of the screen with all of the users names and a little avatar. I'm trying to change the background color of the user information boxes when the user hovers their cursor over them.

```
$('.user_info').hover(function() {
    $(this).prev('td').css("background-color", "#F0F0F0");
    $(this).css("background-color", "#F0F0F0");
}, 
function() {
    $(this).prev('td').css("background-color", "white");
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
});

$('.user_avatar').hover(function() {
    $(this).next('td').css("background-color", "#F0F0F0");
    $(this).css("background-color", "#F0F0F0");
}, 
function() {
    $(this).next('td').css("background-color", "white");
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
});
```

This only appears to work if I redeclare my jquery links at the top of the page whose content I'm loading...

Here's the markup (excuse the inline css, it's just there for debugging):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 10px;" class="user_avatar" id="user_10">
            <img src="images/noavatar.jpg">
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 10px; word-wrap: break-word;" class="user_info" id="user_10">Dave Gilbert
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;" class="user_avatar" id="user_15">
            <img src="images/noavatar.jpg">
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 10px; word-wrap: break-word;" class="user_info" id="user_15">Norman De luca
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 10px;" class="user_avatar" id="user_24">
            <img src="images/noavatar.jpg">
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 10px; word-wrap: break-word;" class="user_info" id="user_24">Test user 1
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;" class="user_avatar" id="user_17">
            <img src="images/noavatar.jpg">
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 10px; word-wrap: break-word;" class="user_info" id="user_17">Test user 2
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 10px;" class="user_avatar" id="user_21">
            <img src="images/noavatar.jpg">
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 10px; word-wrap: break-word;" class="user_info" id="user_21">Test user 3<br />
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;" class="user_avatar" id="user_18">
            <img src="images/noavatar.jpg">
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 10px; word-wrap: break-word;" class="user_info" id="user_18">Test user 4
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 10px;" class="user_avatar" id="user_22">
            <img src="images/noavatar.jpg">
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 10px; word-wrap: break-word;" class="user_info" id="user_22">Test user 5
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 10px;" class="user_avatar" id="user_16">
            <img src="images/noavatar.jpg">
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 10px; word-wrap: break-word;" class="user_info" id="user_16">Leonard Klein
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what version of jquery you are using

Comment: Do you have any other Javascript libraries that you are using... possibly causing a conflict with jQuery?

Comment: Why are you not using CSS for `hover` events?

Comment: It's because you are attaching the events to DOM elements that don't exist yet. You have to bind the events *after* the elements have loaded.

Comment: Your initial snippet has mismatched braces.

Comment: jquery 1.8.2, jquery-ui 1.9.1 and the jquery form plugin

Comment: Edited in the braces. They were there in the code, I just messed up when I pasted them into my post

Comment: @tomc Can you please also post your markup?

Comment: @SamuelCook: At least in this case it makes sense, because he want's to style an element preceding the current element, which isn't possible without a subject selector.

Comment: Added in the markup. 

And yeah, I couldn't do it through css

Comment: @tomc I meant the markup for the loaded content, not the static content.

Comment: added the loaded content markup (although I don't think it's causing the problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are attaching the events *before* the dynamic elements are added, so they are un-effected. To fix this, you would have to do something like this:

```
// attach to the closest parent element that is on the loaded page (not ajax)
$("body").on({ 
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).prev('td').css("background-color", "#F0F0F0");
        $(this).css("background-color", "#F0F0F0");
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).prev('td').css("background-color", "white");
        $(this).css("background-color", "white");
    }
}, '.user_info'); // <- selector here
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because it not available in the dom and you are directly accessing the `.hover()` on the dynamic content for this you have to use `.on()` handler:

```
$(document).on('hover', '.user_info', function() {
   $(this).prev('td').css("background-color", "#F0F0F0");
   $(this).css("background-color", "#F0F0F0");
},function() {
   $(this).prev('td').css("background-color", "white");
   $(this).css("background-color", "white");
});
```

`Instead using $(document)` you can use the closest parent existing div or any element like:

```
$('.prompt_content').on('hover', '.user_info', function() {
   $(this).prev('td').css("background-color", "#F0F0F0");
   $(this).css("background-color", "#F0F0F0");
},function() {
   $(this).prev('td').css("background-color", "white");
   $(this).css("background-color", "white");
});
```

Comment: Note to OP: *"the closest parent existing div"* `.on()` needs to attach the event to an element that already exists when the javascript is run on page load. It can be told to affect dynamically created elements within that existing one.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution did not work... I get the same result as I did with hover

Comment: I guess I should make them supplementary classes instead. It works regardless, though because the duplicates were meant to work as a single element